# How to differentiate streams in Google Cross-Account-Protection (RISC)

Tags: google-identity, secevents

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#duplicated_missed_events) says the `jti` identifies the event and "is unique to the stream". That means it could be repeated in multiple streams. What differentiates the stream? And how can I make sure to only search for JTIs that pertain to the same stream when de-duping events?

Comment: These [documentation](https://openid.net/specs/openid-risc-profile-1_0-01.html#DELIVERYPOLL) might be helpful regarding `jti` claim and security event stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's Cross Account Protection only supports a single stream per GCP project number today. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#config_stream.

So you can only set up multiple streams through multiple projects that represent different apps you build.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Are you assuming just from this part of the documentation or do you have info from somewhere else? It does phrase it as "your project's security event stream", but we'd be somewhat reading between the lines to draw a conclusion just from that. Unless I missed something else

Comment: I also happen to work at Google. :)